Time-reversal without time translation symmetry
In situations where the Hamiltonian is time-independent, time reversal transformation $\hat{T}$ is said to act on the states as $$\hat{T}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{T}e^{-i\hat{H}t}|\psi_0\rangle=\hat{T}e^{-i\hat{H}t}\hat{T}^{-1}\hat{T}|\psi_0\rangle=e^{+i\hat{H}t}|\psi_0\rangle=|\psi(t)\rangle^{*}=|\psi(-t)\rangle,$$
where in the third step I assumed that $|\psi_0\rangle$ is invariant under $\hat{T}$ and also that $\hat{T}$ is an anti-unitary operator that complex-conjugates the scalars, i.e. $\hat{T}\alpha\hat{T}^{-1}=\alpha^{*}$. We therefore find that the action of $\hat{T}$ on $|\psi(t)\rangle$ can be either complex-conjugating the wave-function or flipping the sign of $t$, being both operations completely equivalent.
Now assume a time dependent Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(t)$ that is not time-translationally invariant. For example, assume that it is constant for $t<0$ and starts to vary as a function of time for $t\geq0$.
$$\hat{H}(t)=\begin{cases}\hat{H}_0,&t<0,\\\hat{H}(t),&t\geq0.\end{cases}$$
This Hamiltonian is obviously not time-translateally invariant, and in particular, $\left[\hat{H}(t),\hat{H}(t')\right]\neq0$.
Now, if I act with $\hat{T}$ on $|\psi(t)\rangle$, I get $$\hat{T}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{T}\mathcal{T}e^{-i\int^t\hat{H}(t')dt'}|\psi_0\rangle=\hat{T}\mathcal{T}e^{-i\int^t\hat{H}(t')dt'}\hat{T}^{-1}\hat{T}|\psi_0\rangle=\mathcal{T}e^{i\int^t\hat{H}(t')dt'}|\psi_0\rangle=|\psi(t)\rangle^{*}$$
However, in this case, $|\psi(t)\rangle^{*}\neq|\psi(-t)\rangle$ due to the time-ordered symbol. To see this, note that is one time-evolves the initial state backwards on time, the evolution is trivial because the Hamiltonian is time independent. On the other hand, if one time-evolves onwards, the evolution is highly non trivial and must generally be solved numerically. Therefore, a trivial and a non-trivial solution cannot be related just by a complex conjugation operator.
My question therefore is: how does $\hat{T}$ acts on states that evolve under time-dependent Hamiltonians? Is the anti-unitary nature of $\hat{T}$ enough to ensure that it really acts as a time-reversal operator, or must additional structure be included in the operator so that it fulfills $\hat{T}|\psi(t)\rangle=|\psi(-t)\rangle$?

Time reversal operator is defined through a sequence of postulates, that generally includes

Its action on position operator $T\mathbf xT^\dagger = \mathbf x$
Its action on momentum $T\mathbf p T^\dagger = - \mathbf p$
Conservation of probability $TT^\dagger = \mathbb I$.

If the system has spin, we should include the postulate of spin under the action of time reversal op. This definition is general and does not necessary related to Schrodinger equation.
When we apply such operator in quantum states, we get the time reversed state
$$
|\psi_R(t)\rangle = T|\psi(-t)\rangle.
$$
If the state $|\psi(t)\rangle$ satisfy the Schrodinger equation
$$
i\hbar {d\over dt} |\psi(t)\rangle = H |\psi(t)\rangle
$$
The time-reversed state satisfy
$$
i\hbar {d\over dt} T|\psi(-t)\rangle = T\left(i\hbar {d\over d t'} |\psi(t')\rangle\right)  = TH(t')|\psi(t')\rangle = TH(t')T^\dagger T|\psi(t')\rangle
$$
Or, shortly
$$
i\hbar {d\over dt} |\psi_R(t)\rangle = (TH(-t)T^\dagger)|\psi_R(t)\rangle.
$$
In general case, the last equation could be a completely different equation.

Generally, $T|\psi(t)\rangle $ will not be $|\psi(-t)\rangle$, only in special cases it is true, as you discovered by other ways.

Here's an intuitive picture: even classically, merely reversing momentum does not give you a time-reverse trajectory if the Hamiltonian itself is time-dependent.  You have to also reverse H(t), which is not covered by the usual classical or quantum time reversal.
